# StackExchange inbox disappeared

Tags: bug, status-completed, global-inbox

Just after the migration my Stack Exchange inbox has stopped working.

Are the messages lost? Can I recover them?

[image]

Comment: It works for me …

Comment: @KonradRudolph it got fixed earlier, seemed to have just a short delay

Comment: I just got notified for the new comments. But still missing the old ones.

Comment: Ok they are back.

Comment: Please don't add FIXED to the title -- that's what the [status-completed] tag is for.

Comment: @mbratch That is probably related to [this bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184323/my-inbox-suddenly-emptied-on-so) (which was posted an hour ago)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We were experiencing some issues with the back-end services for inboxes. I have issued a reload of yours but everyone who had issues will see it fixed automatically as cache expires.

Comment: Still empty here.. how long might it take?

Comment: Empty here as well, except for my latest messages.

Comment: Still empty here as well.

Comment: OK, after two forced re-logins it's working again. Thanks!

Comment: My Inbox is broken as well. Still is.